# How to get request parameter after Apache rewrite use /

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

Here is the content of my Apache `.htaccess` file. After rewrite by **Apache**, I can not get any request `Uri` through PHP's super variable `$_REQUEST`.

So what should I do? Otherwise, change `index.php/$1` to `index.php?$1`.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Question is what you want. We cannot tell you that. Most likely `index.php?$1` _is_ indeed what you are looking for. Why don't you simply test it?

Comment: Thank you. Now I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get what I want.

Comment: Sure, that is also possible, though not exactly straight forward since it forces you to parse the URI manually.